# Using 'any' with plural nouns

Tags: singular-vs-plural

I know that the word 'any' can be used with plural and singular nouns depending on the location of the word 'any', however, I feel using the plural noun following my sample sentence is incorrect.

> The university forbids students to smoke in any buildings.

I think the 's' in "building" is unnecessary. Can someone comment and explain this please?

Comment: It's definitely unnecessary, but I don't think it's incorrect.

Comment: Negative polarity "any", like "no", is compatible with both singular and plural nouns. So I don't think this is incorrect. But "The university forbids smoking in all buildings" or "Smoking is forbidden in all university buildings" would be simpler.

Comment: It might be intended to be emphatic (no smoking anywhere throughout all buildings), although it certainly doesn't mean anything different.

Answer (score 1):

I would use "any buildings" only where the context implied that it could refer to one or more than one building at the same time; for example:

> Give me the names of any buildings over four storeys high.

But you can smoke in only one building at a time, so I would unhesitatingly say:

> The university forbids students to smoke in any building

Answer (score -2):

Because building is a countable noun, you should use the plural form of it after ANY.

Comment: You can use the strong form with singular countable. 'It could be any building.' is grammatical.  http://dictionary.cambridge.org/grammar/british-grammar/any 'The university forbids students to smoke in any building on campus' is also grammatical.

Comment: This answer is wrong.